# Left Margin responsiveness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am sorry to disturb you all, but i want to understand how a certain margin responsiveness works.
As you can see on this site http://www.trade-ideas.com/about-us/ the navbar, the paragraphs, the h1, h2 and the footer maintain the same left-margin as you resize the browser window (with firefox the effect it's more clear).
It's like when the elements reach the limit of the left margin (that is mean zero), they restart just on the same distance (the same margin-left) that they where before i was starting resize my browser width.
I've noticed that the navbar included in bootstrap also has this left margin responsiveness: as i resize in width my browser's window, the navbar continue to stay in the same left-margin range, restarting every time he reach the zero margin-left.
In fact, on this bootstrap page you can find the exact same effect in all the page's elements (the navbar and the div box on the body) : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

With firebug i've tried to search what parameter set this particular effect, but i'm not an expert, and i didn't find a solution.
So, my question is: this left-margin responsiveness it's generated by a set of @media queries instructions to a set of width? Or there is something that i'm missing?
Thank you in advance for all the help that you'll give me.

Andrew

p.s.: i noticed that on http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ if i delete "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" the effect that i need doesn't show up anymore.
I tried to create a div container with that margin auto on my site, but i was not  able to ricreate the effect (maybe that "margin-left-right:auto" it's just a part of the effect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media queries are the ones that make sure the website is responsive. The example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ is using media queries to set the width of the container. If you set the media queries to change when the screen width is 700px and when you make the width of the screen smaller. The media queries will register the px of the screen and when the width of the screen is equal 700px the container will change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I was not sure that there were any media queries on that pages. A confirm of my doubts is really helpful. Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: I usually use Inspect Element in Google Chrome and when you shrink the screen the media queries start to appear.

Comment: thank you for the tip, i'll use it next time. With firebug they didn't show up. Very Helpful :)